# Get User Input and Add it to last index of Array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, user-input

I need to know how can I add an item to an existing array using a user input.

I tried something like this:

```
Dim MyArray(100) as String

UBound(MyArray) = Inputbox("What's the name of your new array item?")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ubound(myArray)` returns a `Long` datatype, it literally return the length/size of the array.

If you want to read or assign a value then you must fully qualify the array ie.

`MyArray(ubound(myArray)) = "new Value"` or `MyArray(100) = "new Value"`

```
Sub Main()

    Dim MyArray(100) As String

    MyArray(UBound(MyArray)) = InputBox("What's the name of your new array item?")

    MsgBox MyArray(UBound(MyArray))

End Sub
```

Comment: Mehow, lets say that currently, the array has only 4 itens of 100.
The statement will add the new array item to the 100 position.

How can I add it to the next available position, that is, the 5th position?

Comment: a [**collection**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579457/why-use-arrays-in-vba-when-there-are-collections) would be more suitable in that case. You wouldn't have to specify the size of your collection at start and a simple method like `collectionObj.Add()` adds new items to the end of the current queue.

Comment: If you really wanted to use an array and add item to the next empty(unassigned) element in array this would be a good new question.

Comment: I did not know about Collections object, Mehow. 
It seems more interesting than Arrays.. 
I'll try reading something about them now.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamic array instead:

```
Dim MyArray() As String

' Then to add a new element:
Redim Preserve MyArray(1 to SafeUBound(MyArray) + 1)
MyArray(SafeUBound(MyArray)) = InputBox("Who's yer daddy?")

Function SafeUBound(vArray As Variant) As Long

Dim x As Long

On Error Resume Next
x = UBound(vArray)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    SafeUBound = x
Else
    SafeUBound = 0
End If

End Function
```

The call to SafeUbound is necessary because calling UBound or LBound on an uninitialized array will throw an error.